# React Component does not re-render on state change?

Tags: reactjs, render, setstate, use-state

I am changing the sort order and setting state in that order but it does not get automatically re-rendered.
In the function sortVal(), I've set state setAllQues(sortArr1) which actually sets allQues array to sortArr1 which should get rendered.However, if I click on sorting button('Latest', 'A-Z', 'Z-A', or 'Oldest ') and I console log it, the array allQues is perfectly sorted but doesn't get re-rendered.

```
const TopQuestions = () => {
const [allQues, setAllQues] = useState(null);
const [sortWay, setSortWay] = useState('Latest');
//const [sortArr, setSortArr] = useState([]);
const format1 = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

let sortArr1 = [];

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/questions')
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (sortWay === 'Latest') {
                data.sort((a, b) => b.sortOrder - a.sortOrder);
            }
            setAllQues(data);
        });
}, []);

const sortVal = val => {
    let sortArr1 = allQues;

    console.log(sortArr1, 'sortArr1');

    if (val === 'Latest') {
        sortArr1 && sortArr1.sort((a, b) => b.sortOrder - a.sortOrder);
        setAllQues(sortArr1);
    } else if (val === 'AZ') {
        sortArr1 && sortArr1.sort((a, b) => a.ques.localeCompare(b.ques));
        setAllQues(sortArr1);
    } else if (val === 'ZA') {
        sortArr1 && sortArr1.sort((a, b) => b.ques.localeCompare(a.ques));
        setAllQues(sortArr1);
    } else if (val === 'Oldest') {
        sortArr1 && sortArr1.sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);
        setAllQues(sortArr1);
    }
    console.log(allQues, 'allQues');

};

    return (
    <div className='mx-56 pt-16 border-l-2'>
        <div className='px-4'>
            <div className='flex justify-between'>
                <div className=''>
                    <h1 className='text-3xl text-left mb-6 '>Top Questions</h1>
                </div>
                <div className='flex mb-6'>
                    <div className=' transition duration-300 ease-out border-2 border-r-0 border-gray-1050 px-2 py-1 hover:bg-gray-200 '>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                sortVal('Latest');
                            }}
                            className='text-gray-1150'
                        >
                            Latest
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className=' transition duration-300 ease-out border-2 border-r-0 border-gray-1050 px-2 py-1 hover:bg-gray-200'>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                sortVal('AZ');
                            }}
                            className='text-gray-1150'
                        >
                            A-Z
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className=' transition duration-300 ease-out border-2 border-r-0 border-gray-1050 px-2 py-1 hover:bg-gray-200 '>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                sortVal('ZA');
                            }}
                            className='text-gray-1150'
                        >
                            Z-A
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className=' transition duration-300 ease-out border-2 border-gray-1050 px-2 py-1 hover:bg-gray-200 '>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                sortVal('Oldest');
                            }}
                            className='text-gray-1150'
                        >
                            Oldest
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {allQues &&
                allQues
                    .filter(allQue => (allQue.ques, allQue.author, allQue.dateTime))
                    .map(allQue => (
                        <EachQuestion
                            id={allQue.id}
                            ques={allQue.ques}
                            quesBrief={allQue.quesBrief}
                            author={allQue.author}
                            dateTime={allQue.dateTime}
                            hashes={allQue.hashes}
                        />
                    ))}
        </div>
    </div>
);

};

export default TopQuestions;
```

Comment: Sort sorts in-pace so it's the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try put `allQues` state on the array dependencies of second useEffect parameter, because it make watch the state which is allQues, then when `allQues` changed so component do side effect on first parameter of `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/questions')
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (sortWay === 'Latest') {
                data.sort((a, b) => b.sortOrder - a.sortOrder);
            }
            setAllQues(data);
        });
}, [allQues]);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But as I am setting default way to sort as 'Latest' in sortway, I also had to setSortWay('AZ') for ex, to get it to stay in that state in the sortVal function.

Answer (score 4):

Don't directly sort sortArr1, first of all, make its copy and then sort that copy and then set sorted array into the state.

you can copy array as below:

```
let copiedArr = [...sortArr1];
copiedArr.sort(sortFn);

setSortArr1(copiedArr);
```

Comment: For that purpose itself, I have taken the sortArr1 to copy elements of allQues.